# Asking for half stipend in mid-way of an internship

Tags: salary, internship, websites

So, since past 5 months, I have been doing this work-from-home internship for writing few tutorials on programming. I was doing at really slow pace in the beginning because of my college but now in my vacations, I have completed more than 50% of the work.

The first party (who is a guy) had agreed to provide me with some amount depending on how good I was. I have never met them face to face, it was either with emails, or text messaging. Although they have a great longstanding website, but I am not 100% sure about the security. Now since it had been more than 5 months, I think I deserve at least half the amount that they are agreeing to pay. Also, I don't want them to feel as I if I am about to leave or anything because I am not.

Now comes the main part. How should I approach them in the best possible way and ask for the half stipend?

Comment: You might want to go back and re-word what you said. My understanding is that you have a remote internship writing tutorials with payment based on completion of the work. I also presume that you signed a work agreement or contract regarding this work. Does the contract state that you would be compensated at 50% of work completed or only at 100%?

Comment: @FrankFYC No there wasn't any contract. It's safe to say that website is owned by few guys only, thus I felt like demands can get a little flexible in this case and there is no need of signing any contract.

Comment: So where is the internship aspect?

Comment: @Saharsh there's only no need of signing a contract if you don't need a guarantee of getting paid...

Comment: An agreement to pay "depending on how good" sounds to be intentionally vaguely worded to allow complete non-payment.  I would sort this out now.  Half-way through should be sufficient to allow your employer to make a judgement on the quality of the work, and commit to a particular pay rate and payment timeline, IN WRITING.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a scam but it's probably a scam. Insist on money before you go any further.

Answer (score 2):

First, get **everything** in writing. Always. "This person told me..." is many times useless should  you have to go to court to prove they didn't do as they promised.

If the person agreed in writing that you would get paid part of the stipend before the work was complete, then you approach them and ask for the money.

If not, then you have no expectation on receiving anything before the work is complete. This would be like me going to my employer at 1 week through the pay period and asking for half my pay in advance because I think I should get it. While this would be nice, I'm thinking my payroll people would laugh me out of the office, if not the building (and likely in a white coat...)

Comment: I see both of the answers mentions how important a written contract is. Although I have contacted them and received a satisfactory reply, I think this was helpful for me. I'll keep this in mind for my future internships/freelancing too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Saharsh, I think the greatest part of this internship won't be that you'll someday gloss over the code you wrote.  I think it'll be the business skills you'll learn from understanding that people can tell you just about anything they want to get you to do some work for free, but as the other response here (as of right now) spells out, not much of that matters if it's not in writing.

You don't have anything in writing - at least, that you've informed us about - that promises a specific payment amount, or a specific scope of work.  You're guessing that you're halfway done.  What if you get to 99% complete, and then these people decide to widely expand the scope of the work?  Because you have no written scope of work, and no written anything on how much your payment is supposed to be, you'll be stuck.

I'd suggest you draw up, sooner than later, a contract that gives specifics to these details.  If you encounter resistance, QUIT.  Someone concerned with treating you fairly will not have a problem with documenting what's expected from themselves and you.  But right now, you're wide open to having your  trusting nature being used against you.  Let's suppose you took this in front of a court of law to argue for your stipend:  what could you prove???

Don't believe me?  Visit the Freelancing stack exchange and see how many questions are exactly like yours.

Lastly: asking for a stipend on the work done thus far *might* be appropriate if you're generating a contract on paper at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. I have already contacted the guys over there and received their statement. Although this was a great advice!